# why is the formular i created in my r-code not working

Tags: r, r-formula

Help pls! I ve trying to create this BMI formular to run as code. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Still a newbie in this world of coding. Here's what I attempted

```
weight= 79
height= 179
BMI<= as.formula((weight/(height)^2)*703)
print BMI
```

Comment: You don't need `as.formula`, `BMI <- weight/(height^2)*703`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
weight <- 79
height <- 179
BMI <- (weight/(height)^2) * 703
print(BMI)
[1] 1.73331
```

Why is the number "703" in there?

Shouldn't it be:

```
weight <- 79
height <- 179
BMI <- (weight/(height/100)^2)
print(BMI)
[1] 24.65591
```

Comment: The first one is what I was trying to do and it worked! Thank you @jared_mamrot  I just enrolled into a data analytics program and this was a practice work given to us, I have no idea why there is "703" is in there. lol

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can make this a function pretty easily.  However I'm pretty sure you should double check the equation itself.  If I'm not mistaken, BMI is calculated using weight(kg)/(height in meters^2).  I'm very sure that someone who weighs 79kg and is 179 cm (1.79m) tall does not have a BMI of well below 1, which is the result using 179 cm as the height input.

```
BMI<- function(weight, height) {
weight/(height^2)
}

bmi<- BMI(79, 179)
[1] 0.002465591

bmi<- BMI(79, 1.79)
[1] 24.65591
```

Comment: Thank you @s.harkins . This was a practice work given to us in class, the numbers are just hypothetical. Someone has answered me and shown where I went wrong, but I'll try this way out and see. I'm happy to just have the help you've offered.